# await Task.Delay doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, async-await

I think I'm missing something but I cant seem to get await to work in .net 4.5

Does anyone know the correct syntax here? everywhere I've looked seems to use exactly what I've got. (see [Proper use of Task.Delay to delay key presses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572559/proper-use-of-task-delay-to-delay-key-presses))

[image]

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of your code? Did you actually read the error message?

Comment: as much as svick's comment might be considered a little harsh, he *does* have a good point - the compiler team put in an excellent error message here, telling exactly how to fix the problem. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to invoke an asynchronous method from a lambda.  You're probably missing the `async` at the start.  For example"

```
SomeMethod(async () =>
    {
        //...
        await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
    });
```

Comment: You should avoid using `void`-returning `async` methods (or lamdas) if possible. They make error handling more difficult.

Comment: just to make it explicit for others that run across this, you can just change the type of the local var from Action to Func<Task> in order to resolve svick's concern.  This isn't a comment directed at you two, just trying to help others that may not 'get' how they would change the code so they could get a Task out of it. :)

Comment: I assumed he was calling a method that took a delegate and only needed the `async` so that he could call await on `Task.Delay`.  I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `async` on your method...the one that encloses your block of code.

- [What's the difference between Task.Start/Wait and Async/Await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519414/whats-the-difference-between-task-start-wait-and-async-await)
- http://www.itwriting.com/blog/4913-a-simple-example-of-async-and-await-in-c-5.html
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx